# Parsing JSON into tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I am receiving a JSON file from a remote server and I can display the result in a label. The JSON data is working fine when I call function `processJSONData()` and the tableview works fine with a simple array. How can I incorporate both to display the result from the JSON file in the tableview? Kindly look at the code below and edit. Many thanks:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var countryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var capitalLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //processJSONData()
                  self.myTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.myTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func processJSONData(){
        let urlPath = "http://dubaisinan.host22.com/service1.php"
        let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url,completionHandler: {(data, respose, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            }
            else {
                    self.abc(data)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }


    func abc(data:NSData)
    {
        var parseError: NSError?

        let result:AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &parseError);

        if(parseError == nil){
            if let dictResult = result as? NSArray{

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.countryLabel.text = dictResult[2]["Capital"] as? String
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var items = ["One","Two", "Three","Four"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.myTableView

        .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is confusing.  Do you simply want to add or use additional fields in your table view cell with data?

Comment: Hi Michael, I just want to display the following JSON result from a remote db into a tableview: [{"Country":"Canada","Capital":"Otawa"},{"Country":"France","Capital":"Paris"},{"Country":"England","Capital":"London"}]. Like I mentioned, the JSON file is working fine and one of the items can be displayed in a label. How can I display the info in a tableview? Thank you.

Comment: That totally depends how you want your cells to look and what information you want them to display. Post your example JSON in the question and possibly show how you want your table cell to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the JSON data into a class-level variable, which you will define outside of any function, similar to how you defined "items". Assuming you have a list of countries with the capital of each, this might look like so:

```
var countryAndCapitalData = [(country: String, capital: String)]()
```

This could be improved by first defining a struct to contain your data:

```
struct CountryInfo
{
    name: String
    capital: String
    init(name:String, capital:String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.capital = capital
    }
}
```

which lets you define your data array as an array of CountryInfo:

```
var countryAndCapitalData = [CountryInfo]()
```

Then in your "abc" function (which I insist you rename to something like processCountryData), store the pairs of country name + capital name strings in countryAndCapitalData. For example:

```
countryAndCapitalData.append(CountryInfo(countryName, capitalName))
```

Use a For loop to loop through values in dictResult. Creating countryName and capitalName depends on the structure of your JSON, but from your example it might look like this:

```
for countryDictionary in dictResult[2]
{
    if let countryName = countryDictionary["country"], let capitalName = countryDictionary["capital"]
    {
        countryAndCapitalData.append(CountryInfo(countryName, capitalName))
    }
}
```

Then in tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath, populate the cell label(s) with `countryAndCapitalData[indexPath.row].name` and `countryAndCapitalData[indexPath.row].capital`.

And finally, be sure to reload the table after the loop (thanks Eugene):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Apologies for any compilation errors, as I'm typing this from a Windows machine.

Comment: Thank you Skypecakes. May I please ask you to edit the above code to insert the suggested modifications.

Comment: How about you give it a try and let us know what problems you run into? You'll understand it better if you do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you skypecakes. self.myTableView.reloadData() solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you assign your parsing result to global "items" and reload tableview with new data anywhere.

could be done here

```
if let dictResult = result as? NSArray{
    self.items = dictResult
    self.myTableView.reloadData()

///the rest of the code
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your `items` property in `abc` method call and then refresh the table:

```
func abc(data: NSData) {
   // Do something with data
   items = .. // processed data
}

var items: [String]? {
    didSet {
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.addOperationWithBlock {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, I like this elegant way: and pay attention:  reloadData() should be call on Main Thread!